# How find and use direct link to image uploaded in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this image on Google Drive:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zdEBhYircl9-P9Wtx-QyTgmxgskGLcEq/view?usp=sharing

And I use this script to send the image along with the text to Telegram:

```
function EnviarTelegram(botSecret, chatId, photoUrl, caption) {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + botSecret + "/sendPhoto?caption=" + encodeURIComponent(caption) + "&photo=" + encodeURIComponent(photoUrl) + "&chat_id=" + chatId + "&parse_mode=HTML");
}
```

But when I try to use the formula in the spreadsheet to send the message, it returns in error for not being able to get the image.

When I use (deleting this part `view?usp=sharing`):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zdEBhYircl9-P9Wtx-QyTgmxgskGLcEq/

It ok to send the message, but sends only the thumbnail of the image, does not send the original image, so it goes with low quality.

Is there a way to use the original image or just this low quality thumbnail?

Comment: In your situation, how about using `webContentLink` like `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id={fileId}`? [Res](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) But, in this case, the file is required be publicly shared. Please be careful this. Or, if you don't want to publicly share the file, how about using the modified thumbnail link? In this case, you can see the sample script at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66961918

Comment: How about posting my comment as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: I agree, you can put it as an answer and I will add it as the solution!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your situation, I would like to propose the following 2 patterns.

- Pattern 1:

  - Use `webContentLink` like `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id={fileId}`. This URL can be created using the file ID.
  - In this case, please publicly share the file as the viewer.
- Pattern 2:

  - When you cannot publicly share the file, how about using the modified thumbnail link?
  - When `=s220` of the thumbnail link is replaced with `=s1000`, you can change the image size.
  - In this case, you can see the sample script at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66961918)