# When sending image of a spreadsheet graph to Telegram, the image sent is always the same outdated

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, google-visualization, telegram

The image of the graph I'm trying to send to Telegram is this:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRYIAQWrNu1P9fc0CzBXkMb2jsOCKhrRMoakqeq73BVWHNa6ukJHHK00ZvfNi5QQB2Pr7ACdw3yCBwV/pubchart?oid=1479223143&format=image

The formula I use for shipping is this:

```
function EnviarTelegram(botSecret, chatId, photoUrl, caption) {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + botSecret + "/sendPhoto?caption=" + encodeURIComponent(caption) + "&photo=" + encodeURIComponent(photoUrl) + "&chat_id=" + chatId + "&parse_mode=HTML");
}
```

But when I add the graphic link, it does not send the updated version, it always sends the first version of the image when I first published the image.

The formula I use looks like this:

```
=ENVIARTELEGRAM(W1,W2,"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRYIAQWrNu1P9fc0CzBXkMb2jsOCKhrRMoakqeq73BVWHNa6ukJHHK00ZvfNi5QQB2Pr7ACdw3yCBwV/pubchart?oid=1479223143&format=image",W19)
```

The correct image:

[image]

The old image that is always sent to Telegram:

[image]

Is there any way to force the update of this image that is sent to Telegram?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation of `The old image that is always sent to Telegram:`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail flow for replicating your situation?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike When I activate the formula, the bot on Telegram sends the image of the chart, collecting this image from the link, but the image sent is not the current one that appears on the link when opened by the browser, it sends the first version of when I authorized it the publication of the chart image. Is that what you needed information for? If not, could you give me more details of what you need, please ....

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I tested your URL, I can see your upper image. Unfortunately, I cannot see your lower image. If my understanding is not correct, please tell me.

Comment: @Tanaike Correct, when you open the link through the computer's browser, the first image appears, the updated version of the graph, but when I use the link to send it to the telegram, it is not the one that is sent, it sends the first version (oldest) of the graph image, when I approved the link.

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, fortunately, when the image is retrieved using UrlFetchApp, I can see the upper image. If in the current stage, the API you want to use cannot retrieve the latest image with the same URL, as a workaround, how about creating the latest image as a file on Google Drive and sending the URL of the image? But I'm not sure whether this is the direction you expect. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike What it seems to me is that the Telegram bot API collects a saved thumbnail when the first image is created, when I send the link to a newspaper story, it sends the image attached to that story, so I think it does the same thing , so it takes only the oldest image. And unfortunately I already tried to use the image link in Google Drive but it only sends a thumbnail of it, it does not send the original image, it goes totally without quality.

Comment: Thank you for replying. At first, I deeply apologize that my proposal was not useful for your situation. And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `but it only sends a thumbnail of it, it does not send the original image, it goes totally without quality.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike Okay, when I copy the image link in Google Drive, the bot does not send the original image (as if I were sending the file), you know that little image that appears in Google Drive before you open the file? So, it sends exactly that little image, the thumbnail of the original image.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In order to correctly understand about your situation using the file on Google Drive, can you add the script for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike  The script is the same as the one I shared, the ```ENVIARTELEGRAM``` function, I authorize access for everyone, copy the link and put the link in ```photoUrl```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you provide the sample value of `photoUrl`? I asked about the script for retrieving the value of `photoUrl`. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66662925/how-find-and-use-direct-link-to-image-uploaded-in-google-drive i publish this question for the exactly problem

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I cannot still understand about the sample value of `photoUrl` you tested. I apologize for this. For example, you had used `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zdEBhYircl9-P9Wtx-QyTgmxgskGLcEq/` as the value of `photoUrl`?

Comment: @Tanaike Exactly mate, that's correct!

Comment: From your replying, I proposed 2 sample scripts for retrieving the URL of the image file on Google Drive. Could you please confirm it? If my proposed workaround was not useful for your situation, I apologize. By the way, I thought that this answer might be also the answer for https://stackoverflow.com/q/66662925

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you very much for once again offering to help me, at the moment I am away from my computer because I am having dinner, as soon as I am free here, I will do all the necessary tests!

Comment: Thank you for replying. When my suggested scripts were not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Workaround:

- From the discussions in the comment, I would like to propose the following workaround.

  - Fortunately, when the image is retrieved using UrlFetchApp, I can see the upper image in your question. I thought that this might be able to be used. If in the current stage, the API you want to use cannot retrieve the latest image with the same URL, as a workaround, I would like to create the latest image as a file on Google Drive and send the URL of the image.
- From your comments, also I confirmed that you had used `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zdEBhYircl9-P9Wtx-QyTgmxgskGLcEq/` as the value of `photoUrl`. In this case, the image file cannot be correctly shown. I think that the endpoint is required to be modified.

When this workaround including the modification point is a script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script 1:

In this sample script, the chart image is retrieved from `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pubchart?oid=###&format=image` and the image is created as a file, and then, the thumbnail link is retrieved by modifying the image size.

Before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```
const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRYIAQWrNu1P9fc0CzBXkMb2jsOCKhrRMoakqeq73BVWHNa6ukJHHK00ZvfNi5QQB2Pr7ACdw3yCBwV/pubchart?oid=1479223143&format=image";
const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
const file = DriveApp.createFile(res.getBlob());
const outputUrl = Drive.Files.get(file.getId()).thumbnailLink.replace("=s220", "=s1000");
console.log(outputUrl) // You can see the link at the log.
```

#### Sample script 2:

In this sample script, the chart image is retrieved from `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pubchart?oid=###&format=image` and the image is created as a file, and then, the file is publicly shared and the `webContentLink` is retrieved.

```
const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRYIAQWrNu1P9fc0CzBXkMb2jsOCKhrRMoakqeq73BVWHNa6ukJHHK00ZvfNi5QQB2Pr7ACdw3yCBwV/pubchart?oid=1479223143&format=image";
const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
const file = DriveApp.createFile(res.getBlob());
file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
const outputUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + file.getId();
console.log(outputUrl) // You can see the link at the log.
```

- In this case, the file is required to be publicly shared. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)
- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)

Comment: that's perfect!

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.